# get attributes of a node xquery

Tags: attributes, xquery, nodes

I'm trying to get all attributes of a node using the following code in xquery, logically it should work but it isn't

for $n in $nodes
        return $n/@*

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'it isn't'? Is it giving you an error, returning unexpected results, or returning no results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attribute node must be an attribute of an element node and the result tree cannot contain a standalone attribute node.

**If you want to produce a sequence of name - value for each attribute, do**:

```
for $attr in $nodes/@*
 return
   (name($attr), string($attr), '&#xA;')
```

**For example**, given the following XML document:

```
<t topA="1">
  <a x="2" z="3">
    <b message="Hello"/>
  </a>
  <c y="5"/>
</t>
```

**and applying this query to it**:

```
for $nodes in //*,
    $attr in $nodes/@*
 return
   (name($attr), string($attr), '&#xA;')
```

**the result is**:

```
topA 1 
 x 2 
 z 3 
 message Hello 
 y 5
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i don't know why it isn't working, i know that it should have

Comment: @Noor, It isn't possible to guess what the problem is with so little shown, Please, edit the question and provide a complete (but as small as possible) query that everyone can reproduce. For example, there is no source XML document specified and the part of the query is missing that defines the variable `$nodes`. Please.